# Does monthly social security income gets adjusted by monthly vested benefit

Tags: united-states, pension, social-security

At age 65, I am eligible for a lifetime monthly vested benefit in the amount of a few hundred dollars from my former employer (a non-governmental firm). In the company's benefits handbook, this vested benefit is called "Your straight life annuity monthly benefit".

Shortly after this benefit commences, I am planning to apply for the social security income as well. My former employer did not have any pension plan at the time of my separation from the company but a 401k program, and a vested benefit, so my retirement income will be monthly social security + 401k + monthly vested benefit.

I wanted to know if this monthly vested benefit will reduce my monthly social security income? If yes, would it help if I take the entire vested benefit as a lump sum (if such an option is available) so it won't show up as a monthly income when I apply for my social security benefit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.aarp.org/retirement/social-security/questions-answers/do-pensions-reduce-social-security.html

> If the pension is from an employer that withheld Social Security taxes from your paychecks, it won’t affect your Social Security benefits.

Comment: RonJon, thanks for the response. By social security taxes, do you mean the FICA?

Comment: @Anthony https://www.ssa.gov/thirdparty/materials/pdfs/educators/What-is-FICA-Infographic-EN-05-10297.pdf "**FICA** helps fund both **Social Security** and **Medicare** programs".  FICA was the combo of what are now *Social Security Tax* and *Medicare Tax*.  So... yes.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helps a lot and takes aways my fear about adjust social security income